# my main key word is struggling to perform as there is already domain in that word?

Tags: domains, google-search, seo, competitors

( To respect  the Privacy of our Competitors Brand and their Website Domain name and to    follow Our Company Policy  I changed  Name of the actual Domain and Keywords for this question )

We are running a marketing website which sells Braodband Related Products in our State of India . our Prime Product "Reliance Broadband" and keyword for this Product " Reliance braodband"  (Of course ,this is our Important Keyword for Serach Engine ) is strugling to appear in the top pages bcoz ther is alrady a Website in the same as

**reliancebroadband.com**

our domain is **getbraodband.com**  In Google Search Engine if keyword **reliance broadband** 
then our domain always displayed below next to the our Competitor (reliancebroadband.com)

as per as my knowledge , i think  our website is more SEO frindly , large , Unique Contents than that of Our Competitor's website .and i also feel because their having domain name same as the keyword may they are placing above as us.

Even i changed my page url as **getbraodband.com/reliancebraodband.html** still no Improvement now i want to know  if i create subdomain as ( **reliancebraodband.getbraodband.com**) to compite with the domain **reliancebraodband.com** ..

and as i already mentioned  we have SEO friendly Design and of about 30+ backlinks ,and Unique Content,  **can We place above our Competitor in google SERP** ??

Answer (score 3):

The actual name of a domain name has only minor significance in SEO. The other website is probably showing ahead of you for other reasons such as the number, and quality, of other websites linking to their website. You say you have 30 backlinks, that's not really a huge number, plus are all those 30 backlinks indexed by google? Additionally, 1 backlink from an important website is worth more than 30 links form low ranking sites.